# MFC How to type into a combo box when certain item is selected

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I have created a COMBOBOX in my MFC application.

Lets say I have 3 elements inside it: "apples" "bananas" "Type..."

When "apples" and "bananas" are selected don't allow the user to type into the combobox which is achieved by the `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` property of my COMBOBOX definition.

However when "**Type...**" is selected I want the user to add in a new fruit by typing inside the ComboBox.

So in other words have the ComboBox with the `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` and `CBS_DROPDOWN` property depending on the element selected.

Is this possible?

Comment: That'd be a terribly user-hostile UI. Forcing users to select a particular item, only to have them type in the item they really meant to enter is just annoying. Either allow users to *always* enter a new item, or completely move out the ability to add a new entry into a distinct UI. The latter provides far better discoverability.

Comment: You would have to change the combobox style after it's created, I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, a combo box can have only one of `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`, `CBS_DROPDOWN` or `CBS_SIMPLE` styles, not a combination of them.

You can probably somehow emulate your desired behavior by using the `CBS_DROPDOWN` style and having the edit control disabled (enable it when the user selects **"Type..."**). The  `GetComboBoxInfo()` function (or the `CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO` message) returns the handles of the edit and list controls, among other info.

Or else use the `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` style and display a simple dialog-box (with an edit control and OK/Cancel buttons to add an element to the combo-box)